# Django rename the download files

Tags: html, django

In the server, the file's name is "abc.dat", but I want to rename the files "xyz.doc" when people download it.My server is based on Django.

Comment: Please improve your question..

Comment: no need to improve the "question". I find it quite understandable, and the answer made by @limelights seems to be right to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Serving a file with Django is done by setting it on the response

You can then force the rename on the `filename=` attr of the attachment.
This can be anything really.

It's done like this:

```
response = HttpResponse("read your file here ie. abc.dat", mimetype="application/msword")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % ("xyz.doc")
return response
```

Hope it helps!